# Горизонтальная прокрутка текста

Tags: jquery

Скажите, как сделать самую элементарную горизонтальную прокрутку текста (jQuery слайдер)?
Т.е. есть 2 блока, и нужно переключать, какой из них показывать.

Comment: [Вам сюда][1]
[1]:https://www.google.ru/search?aq=0&oq=jquery+%D1%81%D0%BB&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Так везде сложно и громоздко.

Answer (score 3):

Для различного вида слайдеров рекомендую использовать плагин [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Там много настроек и эффектов, практически на все случаи жизни. И при этом очень легко настраивается.